# How can I list the directory of multiple folders in a text file for each individual folder?

Tags: command-line, batch

I have a several dozen folders with multiple files in them, and I was wondering how (or if it's possible) to echo the contents of each folder in a text file using, for example, **dir > INDEX.txt** with a batch file or from the command line.

I know that executing **FOR /D %A IN (X:\destinationFolder*.*) DO (DIR >> INDEX.TXT "%A\")** gets me a text file in the parent directory with all of the folders listed with their contents, but can I make individual indices for each folder? Or am I asking too much of batch scripting?

Not sure if it's crucial info, but I'm running Windows 10. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: by indices do you mean just having a bit of space between your dir listings? or could you clarify by adding what you are thinking the output should look like by editing your question

Answer (score 1):

Not really sure what you're looking for here, but throwing this together was more fun than working:

```
@echo off

set "dir=C:\Your\Top\Folder"

del /f /q "%dir%\index.txt"

if exist "%dir%" (
    echo(
    echo Report for:
    echo %dir%
    echo(
    echo Subfolders:
    dir /a:d /o:n /b "%dir%"
    echo(
    echo Files:
    dir /a:-d /o:n /b "%dir%"
    echo(
    echo \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\
)>>"%dir%\index.txt"

for /d /r "%dir%" %%A in (*) do (
    echo(
    echo Report for:
    echo %%A
    echo(
    echo Subfolders:
    dir /a:d /o:n /b "%%A"
    echo(
    echo Files:
    dir /a:-d /o:n /b "%%A"
    echo(
    echo \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\
)>>"%dir%\index.txt"
```

Naturally, you can keep/toss/change any part of this to make your output file look the way you want - so this is really just to give you an idea. This sets a `dir` variable as your top-folder so we can change things up easier. The `if exist` is there just to get the `dir` output for that top-folder - otherwise we have a `for /d /r` command that will loop recursively through it. The output layout is personal preference based on what I found the most appealing (without worrying about it too much) to look at after looping this through several places. You'll notice after setting the `dir` variable the first thing the batch does is delete the index file so I wouldn't have to manually do it after every time I checked it - otherwise `>>` will just keep echo'ing multiple runs to the end of it.

If you were wanting a separate index file for *each* subfolder, all you have to do is enable delayed expansion and nest the main part of the `for` loop like this:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /d /r "%dir%" %%A in (*) do (
    set "name=%%~nA"
    (echo(
    echo Report for:
    echo %%A
    echo(
    echo Subfolders:
    dir /a:d /o:n /b "%%A"
    echo(
    echo Files:
    dir /a:-d /o:n /b "%%A"
    echo(
    echo \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\)>>"%dir%\!name! index.txt"
)
```

This will give you a separate text file with the name of the folder (`%%~nA`) in the title of each one. If you're lazy like me and want to delete the individualized index files prior to running this the *n*th number of times, you can throw an `if exist "%dir%\!name! index.txt" del /f /q "%dir%\!name! index.txt"` immediately after setting the `name` variable in the loop - which I might as well put in a block:

```
for /d /r "%dir%" %%A in (*) do (
    set "name=%%~nA"
    if exist "%dir%\!name! index.txt" del /f /q "%dir%\!name! index.txt"
    (echo(
```

Let me know if you were looking for something totally different, or if this was helpful at all.

References: [dir](https://ss64.com/nt/dir.html) and [for](https://ss64.com/nt/for.html).

Comment: I indeed was looking for a separate index file for each subfolder; I figured it had to do something with enabling delayed expansion, but I wasn't sure how to write the rest of the script. I always get confused when it comes to using the excIamation marks. I know batch is old, but I'm always amazed at how far you guys out there can push it. I'll be using your solution as a study guide. I thank you very much.

Comment: you use the `!` in delayed expansion when a variable's value will change between loop iterations; so in my example, we `set "name=%%~nA"`, since our `%%A` parameter changes, `name` changes with it and we use `!name!` to indicate each separate text file we're outputting to. what else were you looking for it to do if not the code block that's already there?